# Spring data Cassandra converts the keyspace name and table names into lowercase

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to map existing Cassandra tables into java classes using spring data cassandra. The table names have uppercase letters, for example "MyTable". However, when I use @Table("MyTable"), spring data cassandra doesn't recognize the table because it treats the name as lowercase.

Is there any way to tell spring data cassandra to not convert the names into lowercase?

Sample code:

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

@Table("MyTable")
public class MyTable {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by adding (forceQuote = true) to @Table annotation.

```
@Table(value = "MyTable", forceQuote = true)
public class MyTable {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cassandra's CQL, identifiers like keyspace, table, and column names are case insensitive.  If you desire to use mixed case you must quote your names, i.e.:

```java
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

@Table("\"MyTable\"")
public class MyTable {

}
```

That being said, I would highly recommend not using mixed case identifiers.  While it works, it creates a lot of complexity in having to worry about quoting everything.  The convention I see most with Cassandra is to use all lower case use  `_` as a separator of words, i.e. `my_table`.  You can still use `MyTable` as your class name to meet java conventions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. The following exception is thrown:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: given string ["MyTable"] is not a valid quoted or unquoted identifier

Comment: ah, I didn't realize at the time that there was a separate option for this, glad you figured it out!